# Make: extract the target path segment that follows a known one

Tags: makefile, gnu-make, gnu

I am trying to optimize our build targets. In our current process we have separate targets for 32bit & 64bit build. Due to separate targets we have hundreds of targets in our build flow. Where we try to make it global i.e. one target for both 32-bit and 64-bit build. I'm trying to achieve this with the code below.

Target/Output directory for 32-bit build should be like:

```
/test/scratch/<client_name>/Linux/...
```

Target/Output directory for 64-bit build should be like:

```
/test/scratch/<client_name>/Linux-64bit/...
```

So based on above Target directory paths I am searching the string `Linux` using `$(findstring)` function and proceed with 32-bit command to run. Else it will run 64bit command as shown below.

```makefile
RELEASE_FILES := $(TARGET_DIR)/build/test/csimtime.c
$(RELEASE_FILES): $(TGTDIRFILES)/%: %
ifneq (Linux,$(findstring $(OS),$@))
    $(test_lib_32)
else
    $(test_lib_64)
endif
```

`$(TARGET_DIR)` variable is passed as parameter to make command

```
make TARGET_DIR=$(TGT32) all32
```

For 64-bit we will pass `TARGET_DIR=$(TGT64)` instead.

Note: test_lib_32/64 above are macro definition in other make file which we are including in current make file.

It works fine as expected, But I am not sure whether this is the best way? And I notice one problem here, Generally `TGT32`/`TGT64` variable which we are passing has values either:

```
/test/scratch/<client_name>/Linux/ (for 32bit)
```

or

```
/test/scratch/<client_name>/Linux-64bit/... (for 64bit)
```

If someone creates a client with client_name 'Linux' string it wont work. It will always go to `if` block and try to run 32-bit command even when we run 64-bit build. How can I handle this?

I am looking for getting the string after 'client_name' in above path.. Could please help?

Comment: Maybe you want to take a look at [gmtt](https://github.com/markpiffer/gmtt#call-down-towordlist) which lets you search in a list from the end towards the beginning. You first have to separate your path elements by replacing ´/´with a space of course.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your target directory name is always something like:

```
/test/scratch/<client_name>/Linux/...
```

and there is no `/` character and no spaces in `<client-name>`, you can base your test on the exact position of `Linux` (or `Linux-64bit`) in the path:

```
TYPE := $(word 4,$(subst /, ,$(TARGET_DIR)))

ifeq ($(TYPE),Linux)
<something>
else ifeq ($(TYPE),Linux-64bit)
<something-else>
else
$(error Unknown type: $(TYPE))
endif
```

**EDIT** if the position is not constant but you know what `<client-name>` is, and there is no `/` character and no spaces in `<client-name>`, you can extract the name of the directory that follows `<client-name>` in `$(TARGET_DIR)` like this:

```
TAIL := $(subst /, ,$(TARGET_DIR))
$(foreach w,$(TAIL),$(eval TAIL := $(wordlist 2,$(words $(TAIL)),$(TAIL)))$(if $(patsubst $(CLIENT_NAME),,$(w)),,$(eval TYPE := $(word 1,$(TAIL)))))

all:
    @printf 'TYPE = $(TYPE)\n'
```

Demo:

```
$ make TARGET_DIR=/a/b/test-client/Linux/c/d CLIENT_NAME=test-client
TYPE = Linux
$ make TARGET_DIR=/a/b/c/d/test-client/Linux-64bit/e/f/g CLIENT_NAME=test-client
TYPE = Linux-64bit
```

Explanation:

- `TAIL := $(subst /, ,$(TARGET_DIR))` replaces the `/` characters in `$(TARGET_DIR)` by one space, such that it becomes a list of words (one per directory in the path), and assigns the result to variable `TAIL`.
- `$(foreach w,$(TAIL),...)` evaluates `...` with variable `w` set successively to each word of `$(TAIL)`.
- `$(eval TAIL := $(wordlist 2,$(words $(TAIL)),$(TAIL)))` re-assigns variable `TAIL` by removing the leading word.
- `$(if $(patsubst $(CLIENT_NAME),,$(w)),,...)` evaluates `...` if `$(w)` equals `$(CLIENT_NAME)`.
- `$(eval TYPE := $(word 1,$(TAIL)))` assigns the first word of `$(TAIL)` to variable `TYPE`.

There may be simpler ways to do the same...

Comment: Renaud, Thank You for reply... Position of Linux/Linux-64bit is not same all the time..It depends on user perforce client root directory... So is there any way like finding a string after the <client_name> instead of using index '4' above?

Comment: But do you know what `<client-name>` is? May I suggest that you update your question with a more accurate description? You could remove most of it and keep only this: how to extract the path segment that follows a known one? Or something equivalent.

Comment: <client-name> is depends on user...Lets consider it is static for now... Please consider the client-name as 'test-client' .. Can you update the answer accordingly.. So that i can change my make scripts based on that condition.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly then you get problems with the following `$(TARGET_DIR)` value:

```
 /.../Linux/.../Linux-64bit
```

The problem is that you are testing on the value of `$@`:

```
 /.../Linux/.../Linux-64bit/some/other/file
```

As you can see that makes it impossible to decide which `Linux` in the path should be used for the decision.

I would suggest to try this instead:

```makefile
# if $(TARGET_DIR) ends with /Linux -> 32-bit build
$(RELEASE_FILES): $(TGTDIRFILES)/%: %
ifneq ($(filter %/Linux,$(TARGET_DIR)),)
        $(test_lib_32)
else
        $(test_lib_64)
endif
```

Comment: Stefan, Thank you for your reply.. I am sorry if my question is not clear.. In my case there is no way of having both Linux/Linux-64bit in the same path. As i mentioned for 32bit the target path should be '/test/scratch/<client_name>/Linux/<path_continues> ' & for 64 bit /test/scratch/<client_name>/Linux-64bit/<path_continues> .. Linux/Linux-64bit wont come at the end.. It will come after <client_name>.. Path wont change it is constant.. Could you help me parsing the target file path and get the string after <client_name> and checking whether it is Linux/Linux-64bit.. I guess it would work?

Comment: But somewhere the *root* of all `$(TARGET_DIR)` variables must be defined, i.e. the path that does not include `/<path continues>`. That is the variable that you need to check in your conditional. If you do not have such a root variable, then you should introduce one.

Comment: Okay...Yes i have root variable 'TGT32' In one of the config.mak file..You mean to say .. Instead of checking with $@ ,I should have 'if' conditional check with $(TARGET_DIR) TO see if it has 'Linux'/'Linux-64bit' in it right ? Root variable value is assigned to <source_dir>/build/Linux or Linux-64bit So i want to get the string after string 'build'.. Could you please tell me is there any way in make to get that sub string after 'build'

Comment: The command line you gave was `make TARGET_DIR=$(TGT32) all32`, so `$(TARGET_DIR)` is your root directory in the makefile. My solution checks how *that root* ends, i.e. in `Linux` or `Linux-64bit`. If that doesn't solve your issue, then I fear that your question is too incomplete to be answered. Could it maybe be that you have a recursive build system where each sub-directory level is passed its own value with `$(MAKE) TARGET_DIR=$(TARGET_DIR)/subdir ...`?

Comment: I think testing _TARGET\_DIR_ is perfectly valid. As you point out your test is a bit smelly. IMHO best would be to split into words on `/` and simply use `$(filter…)`: `is-64bit := $(filter Linux-64bit,$(subst /, ,${TARGET_DIR}))`. For extra robustness you might like to handle pre-existing spaces in _TARGET\_DIR_, and check that exactly one of `Linux` or `Linux-64bit` is present. If the assert fails throw an error with `$(error…)`.